# "olfactory" and "factory" - just a coincidence?

Tags: etymology

As a non native speaker I was always wondering is there is any relation between the words Olfactory and factory. They seem strikingly similar yet there is apparently no connection.

Comment: [**olfactory**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=olfactory) *from Latin **olfactorius,** from **olfact-,** past participle stem of **olfacere** "to get the smell of, sniff," from **olere** "emit a smell, give off a smell of" (see odor) + **facere** "to make" (see **factitious**)*. [**factor(y)**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=factor) *... from Latin **factor** "doer, maker, performer," in Medieval Latin, "agent," agent noun from past participle stem of **facere** "to do" (see **factitious**).* So yes, they share common ancestry from Latin.

Comment: The simplest way to find an etymology is to Google "etymology factory" or whatever.

Comment: @HotLicks I thought an "etymology factory" is a place where they make etymologies.

Comment: @Jay -- It is.  Google "etymology factory" and you will get several etymologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Latin root *[fac](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/facio#Latin)*, means to make or to do.  [This site](http://www.english-for-students.com/fac.html) gives a nice list of words containing the root: including factory- a place where things are made/done, faculty- the ability to make/do, and facilitate- to aid in something being made/done.

Olfactory adds the Latin root *[oleo/ olere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oleo#Latin)*, meaning to emit a smell or an odor, along with the suffix *[-ory](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ory)* meaning pertaining to or serving for.

So put *oleo* together with *fact* and *ory* and you get the sensory organ that serves to make/do (the processing of) smells.